# Subset all rows by group by type

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe:

`df <- data.frame(transaction= c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                 itemType = c("a","b","a","l","l","a","b","l","l","d","d","d"))`

I basically want to keep all rows for a transaction that contain item type "a"

so my output would look like:

```
  transaction itemType
1           1        a
2           1        b
3           1        a
4           3        a
5           3        b
6           3        l
7           3        l
```

How would I write the code to take only transactions that contained a&b?

Comment: `df[df$transaction %in% unique(df$transaction[df$itemType == 'a']),]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use indexing

```
# save all the "transactions" where iteamtype equals "a" to an object called F  
f <-  df[ df$itemType %in% "a" , "transaction"  ]

#optional (look as f)
print(f)
print( unique(f))

# Subset to all the rows which equals one of the "transactions" stored in the object f
df[ df$transaction %in% unique( f ) ,   ]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm aware of that possibility but I need ALL rows for transactions that contain a.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you explain those two lines?

Comment: @daveDo - added notes